# ngrx/effects unit tests using jasmine-marbles

Tags: testing, ngrx, ngrx-effects, jasmine-marbles

When I try to use either `cold` or `hot` functions from `jasmine-marbles`, I keep getting `TypeError: Class constructor Observable cannot be invoked without 'new'`. Anybody know how to resolve this error? Here is what I have below.

```
   import { hot, cold } from "jasmine-marbles";
   import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

   const myAction = hot("--a-", { a: "TEST" };
```

Comment: same for me. I also tried to update jasmine-marbles from 0.2.0 to 0.3.1 but there other problems appear (since I have not updated yet to rxjs 6).

Comment: ... and it seems to appear together with target es2015.

Answer (score 1):

I started to get this error after i changed "target" property in tsconfig.json (at project root) to "es6", thus i restored to old good "es5"